# Is there a way to create a temp 2d array in SQL?

Tags: sql, multidimensional-array, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What I’m trying to do is Table 1 has id  I have to match the id.

To get what I’m looking found trying to create this

```
array { (col1, col2), ... }
```

What I have now is

```
array as 
(
Select x as col1, y as col2 from
Values
( ‘col1’,’col2’), etc … )
Select * from table1
Where table1.col2 = array.col2
```

then get col1

Answer (score 0):

You may need to edit the question to provide more specifics about what your final goal is, but this addresses the 2D array part of the question. You can nest array_construct to create arrays of rows inside of array_agg to construct a 2D array of those rows:

```
select array_agg(array_construct(*)) as TWO_D_ARRAY
from SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.NATION;
```

Remember that this technique is subject to the 16Mb limit (as of April 2023) for any data type in Snowflake.